# Global vs static variables in PHP

Tags: php, static, global-variables

I'm creating a basic framework in PHP. I need to pass data for the current page into different functions, allow them to modify and save it, and then pass it back to the page to be displayed. I was originally planning on storing the data in a global variable like `$GLOBALS['data']`, but I'm starting to think that using a global is a bad idea. So I'm thinking that instead I will put a static variable in the system class, and access it using `system::$data`. So, my question is, which would be better and why?

This:

```
$GLOBALS['data'] = array();
$GLOBALS['data']['page_title'] = 'Home';
echo $GLOBALS['data']['page_title'];
```

Or this:

```
class system
{
    public static $data = array()
}

function data($new_var)
{
    system::$data = array_merge(system::$data, $new_var);
}

data(array('page_title' => 'Home'));
echo system::$data['page_title'];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There really is no difference between a global variable and a `public static` variable. The class variable is namespaced a tiny bit better, but that hardly makes any difference. Both are accessible anywhere at any time and both are global state.

As it happens, I just wrote an exhaustive article on the subject:
[How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: Is there a performance difference? It seems as though globals are not as efficient as using a static variable.

Comment: @Kyle **It doesn't matter.** Seriously. There's probably a difference, but it's so astronomically small as to be irrelevant. Your top priority should be to write code that is maintainable, logical, readable and all the other -ble things code should be. Globals and `public static` variables are both terrible for this purpose.

Comment: @deceze My question - what would you use(pick) between the 2 and why ?

Comment: @ShalomSam As I thought I had said above: neither. There isn't any real difference between the two, and they're both mostly bad. (There are cases where static class members make sense, but global variables should never be used except in a script so tiny that it has practically no scope whatsoever.) Read the article I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

> So, my question is, which would be better and why?

You already sense that there is some problem putting this all into globals. Although you have developed some thoughts to encapsulate things into a class.

I think that is a good starting point. Let's add some more spice to the cooking to get this more fluent at the beginning:

```
$data = new ArrayObject(array());
$data['page_title'] = 'Home';
```

You have created an object now that you can pass along containing your data. Just pass `$data` to the area's where it's needed. No global or global static variable needed.

You can even make that type more concrete later on by extending from [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/ArrayObject) with your own type.

Comment: As an FYI, totally unrelated to this post, we can't migrate questions older than 60 days anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For the record.

Pro of static:

Clarity of the code.  For example:

```
function fn() { 
   System::data()
 }
```

versus

```
function fn() { 
   global $system;
   $system->data()
 }
```

Cons of static:

- If you are using psr-4 then you must add (and include) a new class (and a new file). It impacts the performance even if you use opcache (opcache aleviates it but it's not magic).
- You must define a block of code.

Comment: For the record, you can use `$GLOBALS['system'];` instead of `global` keyword, still I strongly discourage everybody - don't use globals - that's a rule of thumb, when you will really need them, you will know.  BTW: in theory initialization with superglobal `$GLOBALS` is a bit slower - it can take almost 3miliseconds! :-O , however the variable fetch is almost the same as fetching the static variable...